# SSMS query result to excel without zero for float columns

Tags: shell, floating-point, sqlcmd

I am exporting SSMS query result with SQLCMD to .csv file using shell script. But if any of the column in a table is float, it is resulting as 123.0 instead of 123. When I execute the same select query in SSMS, it is 123. How can I get the same value which is showing in SSMS result. And I can't use cast/convert for that particular columns since I am going to export result for multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

That's because SSMS itself rounds floating point values for display purposes while `sqlcmd` is not.

Please let us see some code, especially because you're saying that you cannot use convert.

you could convert the value in your query, and also keep the original, something like this:

```
declare @a float
SELECT @a = 3.33;

SELECT CONVERT(INT, @a), @a
```

Besides that, this might be relevant for you: [here](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/)